# What data models do repositories use?

Tags: design-patterns, repository-pattern

Say I have a Car and a Company object:

```
CarModel
{
   int Id;
   string Name;
   CompanyModel MadeBy;
}

CompanyModel
{
   int Id;
   string Name;
}
```

These are two separate domain objects, each with their own repository.

However when I store a car, I’m not actually including the Company object as well - I only store the id. In that sense I also have a CarEntity object:

```
CarEntity
{
   int Id;
   string Name;
   int MadeByCompanyId;
}
```

But when I read a car into my application, it is more useful to be dealing with the CarModel I defined at the start, which has all the details I need like the company name of who made it.

1. Should my car repository methods deal with CarModel and do mappings to and from CarEntity inside (which would involve using CompanyRepository inside the CarRepository which sounds yucky)?
2. Should my car repository only deal with CarEntity and mapping to CarModel is done by the caller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do prefer the second approach because:

If the developers of `CompanyRepository` make some changes in the function definition, then we will need to make those changes in `CarRepository`. Also, in the first approach, we will be violating the [single responsibility principle](https://stackify.com/solid-design-principles/).

I would suggest that we could use the `CompanyRepository`  in `CarEntityToCarModelMapper` class.